# Docker spawning a container with a backup data

Tags: docker

Lets say I have a docker swam. This swam has services that can use any node in the swarm.

Is this a good practice for creating a good service with regards to backups.

```
FROM unbuntu:latest
CMD ["usr/bin/sh", "/usr/bin/init.sh"]
```

Create an init.sh file that makes a request to a file server to get the latest backup.

the init file simply does a curl to get the backup from a backup server and then extracts the contents into place.

After this the init file starts the required services.

docker node -> on init requests from object store -> overrides the folder which  is mounted on the host volumes

Comment: What happens if the backup server is unavailable while the container is starting up?  What will happen to the data if the container fails while it's running?

Comment: Well, lets just assume that I can keep my server running just fine. Or that i'm smart enough to buy s3 storage when it's necessary. I take backups of the services which are then queried when any service restarts. If the container fails running it will leave the data on the host file system (garbage collected) and nothing bad will happen, expect the next running container may be BACKUP_PRERIOD behind.

Comment: Can you see any holes in that? Or do you have something better>?????